# How do I work around Excel considering "13:12:00" as Date?

Tags: excel, vba

The code makes a web query then inputs the order's status and the date it was shipped, it works most of the time but sometimes it skips the Do Loop when it shouldn't (i.e. it thinks the Time-formatted number is a date).:)

```
            Cells.Find(What:="order shipped", After:=ActiveCell, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    
            Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
            strDateShipped = Selection.Value
            
            If IsDate(strDateShipped) = False Then
                Do
                Selection.Offset(-1).Select
                strDateShipped = Selection.Value
                Loop Until IsDate(strDateShipped) = True
            End If
    
            Selection.Copy
```

Comment: what values can be there? e.g. times, dates and integer. Is 13:12:00 formated as string or as number?

Comment: If `IsDate(strDateShipped)` then also check that  `Int(strDateShipped) = strDateShipped` and if the column might contain an Integer, you could check that it is within some reasonable range for the expected date.

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft's document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) says `IsDate` returns true if the "argument is a Variant containing a date expression or string expression recognizable as a date or time."

So, technically `IsDate` checks the value is **either** a date **or** time. However, VBA seems to consider a time value in a cell as a double value while a date value is taken as a date value. So, `IsDate` behaves like checking whether the value is a date or time.

In your case, `13:12:00` is not different from any other time values. So, I think the cause of the problem is the `13:12:00` is inputted as a string value in the cell.

To deal with different types, the solution is to add the following function to check the value is a date (not time),

```
Function IsDateValue(ByVal v As Variant) As Boolean
    IsDateValue = False
    
    ' Convert value to string
    v = CStr(v)
    
    ' This is date OR time
    If IsDate(v) Then
        ' If serial of the value is equal or more than 1, it is date
        If CDbl(CDate(v)) >= 1 Then
            IsDateValue = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

and change calls of `IsDate` to `IsDateValue` in your code.

```
If IsDateValue(strDateShipped) = False Then
    Do
        Selection.Offset(-1).Select
        strDateShipped = Selection.Value
    Loop Until IsDateValue(strDateShipped) = True
End If
```

By the way, ideally, cells that VBA reads should contain only well-formatted (identical type) data, otherwise a code get complicated with many `if`s and may introduce bugs.

Comment: Wow. This worked. Converting it to serial is smart. Thank you so much, kamocyc. Stay safe.